# Kubuntu GUI freeze issue

Tags: kubuntu, gui, freeze

My friend and me have same problem. Kubuntu GUI freeze issue.
When GUI freeze we can move mouse cursor but could not click anywhere. Keyboard is not working except switching to ASCII console with Ctrl+Alt+F2. ASCII console is working properly.
We have to switch ASCII console and then reboot laptops when this issue occur

This problem is occuring every couple of days since last 2-3 months, sometimes twice a day. We tried many things but no progress.

We are thinking consider to switch linux distrubution because both laptop is our working environment.

My laptop is :

```
Lenovo Thinkpad E15
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @1.80GHz
Radeon RX
32 GB RAM 

lsb_release -a output is 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 
LTS Release: 22.04 
Codename: jammy
```

Kernel is `"Linux executor 5.19.0-38-generic #39~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 17 21:16:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"`

My friend's laptop is:

```
Lenovo ThinkPad E15 Gen3
Amd Ryzen 7 series CPU
AMD radeon
40 GB RAM

lsb_release -a output is
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy​
Kernel is : Distributor ID: Ubuntu
```

Kernel is `"Linux kubuntu 5.15.0-69-generic #76-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 17 17:19:29 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux​"`

We could also share any more information that you requested

Any help would be appreciated

Thx

Comment: Each of you should ask your own question. What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: You should check syslog for any related error messages just during the freeze.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with MESA 22.2.x.  It can be resolved by upgrading to MESA 22.3.0 or later.  See:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1463322/702934

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kwin/+bug/2018671