# kwin becomes unresponsive, need to restart session

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, freeze, mesa, kwin

After upgrading Kubuntu from 18.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS, I'm experiencing occasional "freezing" of the desktop. All the windows lose their edges and I cannot navigate between them. After some time, the desktop stops responding altogether and I need to restart the laptop.
This is very similar to the issue mentioned in this question: [Desktop "freezing" on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458083/desktop-freezing-on-kubuntu-22-04-lts)

Comment: Sorry that is not how this site works. It is strictly a question answer site, not a forum. You can ask a question where this would be the answer and use the answer your own question option in that question.

Comment: You can ask a question and then answer it yourself. Please do so: Edit your question, and add the solution as an answer. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I'm hitting this KDE [Bug #457847 - kwin becomes unresponsive, need to restart session](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=457847). It explains that the problem is caused by a bug in MESA 22.2 [regression: kwin killed by X after updating Mesa (bisected)](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/7674).

As for now I've upgraded MESA to 23.1 using [Oibaf's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers).

**Update 2023-04-18**:

The upgraded drivers do solve my problem. I've been running my KDE for 5 days straight without the bug occurring.

Comment: You do not say if this works.

Comment: I wish I could somehow notify @Paul about this solution, though. He seems pretty upset about switching from KDE to Xfce in his question...

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I've been running into something similar. I've run across many posts complaining that it started in February/March so I wonder if a package update was pushed out that broke it. (I'm also new to Kubuntu 22.04 so I can't say what things were like "before".) I'm trying MESA with Oibaf's PPA as you did to see if that helps. Seems odd because the stock MESA version in Ubuntu 22.04 is older than the one that supposedly introduced the bug (but I know they push out packages with backported changes sometimes). Has everything remained stable for you for the past couple of weeks?

Comment: Yes, @TruismsHounds, I've been running my laptop without problems for several days in a row since I've switched to the latest MESA drivers.

Comment: Thank you.  I have also not run into this issue since upgrading MESA.  I started with the Oibaf repo as you suggested, but have since switched to just using the MESA package set from Ubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on Kubuntu 22.04, after upgrade from 20.04, where everything was rock stable, and I run laptop Latitude E6430 for months without need to reboot.

On 22.04 my laptop sometimes lock-up/freeze. Once I noticed, that:
`/usr/bin/plasmashell`
started to take 100% of use on 3 of 4 CPU cores, it was 2-3s before everything stops working.
For some time I could move mouse, and then it stop to move as well.
Once left laptop for night, and it not wake up from freeze on morning.

Seems like it is plasma issue.
I've upgraded MESA to 23.1 using Oibaf's PPA as well and frequency of lockups reduced to ~1 per day.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+F2/F3 to switch to console, do not work when lock-up/freeze occur

Comment: Well, I believe you are hitting a different bug. Once I've switched to the most recent MESA drivers, I have no issue. And as far as I can tell, the issue was caused by pop-up windows on Plasma - you know those small notification windows that pop up when you get a new e-mail, or Spotify starts playing a new song. Because the freeze would occur more often if I was listening to music all the time, while the Plasma shell did not freeze over the weekend, when the laptop was on but I wasn't using it.
Do you see a correlation between the amount of pop-ups and the frequency of freezes?