# MESA bug-fix update delayed by 12 days on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, kubuntu, 22.04

I've been having problems with MESA on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS with kwin to crashing.  There is a version here that might solve the problem

- [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1%7E22.04.2)

However, when using

```
  apt update
  apt upgrade
```

the newest version of MESA is only being installed on one of my three machines running Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.

For example, the versions of `libglx-mesa0` I have on each machine (after upgrading) are

```
|---------+--------------+---------------------------+---------------------------|
| machine | when updated | version from              | version to                |
|---------+--------------+---------------------------+---------------------------|
|       1 |   2023-05-24 | 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 | 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2 |
|       2 |   2023-02-04 | 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.3         | 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 |
|       3 |   2023-01-31 | 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.3         | 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 |
|---------+--------------+---------------------------+---------------------------|
```

What might be causing the delayed update and how can I force all machines to update to the newest version?

The problem can't be associated with phased updates as they are only supposed to take at most 2 days according to here

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates

Comment: This version is no longer available.  But  jammy-proposed offers `libglx-mesa0:
  Installiert:           22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2
  Installationskandidat: 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3
  Versionstabelle:
     22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3 150
        150 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-proposed/main amd64 Packages`  For testing. Or you wait.

Answer (score 0):

22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2 was deleted from the jammy updates pocket and 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 restored, as the .2 caused a significant regression for users.

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/2020604

There is currently a .3 version in the jammy proposed pocket that potentially fixes the issue with the .2 update.

[https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1%7E22.04.3)

If successfully verified, that .3 revision should become eligible for release to the update pocket in about 7 days.

Comment: Thanks for that info, it's really interesting.  I had also been experiencing some problems with certain graphics not being rendered in Brave and Chrome.  I understood ```patches: Revert two commits causing kwin to eventually crash.``` in the first link in my original most to mean that that version .2 had fixed the kwin problem reported at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1463211/kwin-becomes-unresponsive-need-to-restart-session/1463322#1463322.  That's the bud I'm really keen to see fixed.